# Compile multiple times the same .dll in runtime

Tags: c#, serialization, compiler-construction

I am working on a simple 2D game editor, I want to be able to read from a .cs file, compile and then attach it to objects in runtime (like Unity3D) and be able to edit its properties.

I am compiling them into a .dll file right now, the problem is when I try to re-compile it again because the original .cs files can be updated in runtime as well(it says the file is already being used because the .dll has been loaded into the assembly I suppose)

Is there another way to do this?

**Flow:**

1 - User make / edit a script (.cs file)
2 - User calls a function to Compile Scripts
3 - The program compiles all the .cs files and updates the .DLL file.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible, or at least not practical. It would also help to show what you've tried, since you're trying to do something that is not typical. Usually you would stop your program then recompile.

Comment: I agree with you, this is may not be very practical but can be implemented (Unity3D Engine uses this) and it's a big improvement when developing a game.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than linking the DLL to your project, consider using LoadLibrary() or LoadLibraryEx() to load it before you call any of its functions (and after doing any of your re-compiles), then call FreeLibrary() before doing your re-compile.

Comment: Thanks for your response RobH, can you tell me please how I can use the LoadLibrary/Ex() to load those compiled types into the program?

Comment: LoadLibrary() is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (You can find links to the other two functions, as well as related functions there as well.) When you link your project, don't link the DLL's .lib file into it, as LoadLibrary/Ex() will do that job. (You still have to #include the header(s), though.) Of course, if the user makes changes in the header(s) (to change the API, for instance), then you're out of luck, as you'll have to recompile your project, which of course requires shutting it down first.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to load the assembly and free it when necessary. I only have one problem now. How can I find the types of the loaded assembly? I want to show the user the Types available in the assembly loaded by the LoadLibrary().

Once again thanks for the support ;)

Comment: I think that I can solve this using Shadow Copying, I am going to try and say something later ;)